# GPS provider return null values

Tags: android, gps

I tried to get current location using GPS Providers.

- But it's not working properly as far as I know. In case of Network provider it returns Tower values, not exactly the satellites values.
- Here with I attached some of code samples related to GPS Provider.

---

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f,this);

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        String currentLocation = "Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng;
        txted.setText(currentLocation);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);
        mc.animateTo(p);
    }
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // required for interface, not used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that "use GPS satellites " is enabled, 
go from settings -> location and security-> use GPS satellites.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,this);
```

later you get updates as per your requirement.

Comment: please post your complete activity